# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [24, 2]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was trying to make a stock prediction algorithm and was almost done - I just had to implement the linear SVC algorithm. So, I've cleaned the data, and I want to use the train_test_split library to split the data so that I can fit a predictive model onto it. However, when I try to split the data, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [24, 2]
```

I've been very meticulous and have verified all of my features are the same length - in the format of [[Feature1][Feature2][Feature3][Feature4]] and that my Y is the same length as the data length.

I am using the timeline 2010/01/01 - 2010/01/10 to make it more readable. Unfortunately, after looking at several threads, and some of the documentation, I cannot figure out why my split isn't working. If you have knowledge on whats happening, please let me know.

Predictor class:

```
#I want to use Linear SVC
#Sci Kit Learn
class Predictor:
    def __init__(self, stock):


    from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC as lsvc
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts         

    features = []

    for i in stock.features:
        inner = []

        for ii in i.featureData:
            inner.append(ii)
        features.append(inner)

    y =  stock.two_list

    clf = lsvc(random_state=0, tol=1e-5)

    xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = tts(features, y)

    #clf.fit(xTrain, yTrain)

    #>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    #...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)


    #print(clf.score(xTest, yTest))
```

Run the code here:
https://repl.it/@JacksonEnnis/Stock-Alg

Comment: When you print the shapes of `features` and `y` right before applying the train/test split, what do you get?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin I get that each feature has two items, and that the y also has two items (for the date 2010/01/01 - 2010/01/10) http://notes.io/7r8i

Comment: Looks like the `features` array in your code needs to be transposed before you pass it in to the `train_test_split` -- You can do `np.array(features).T`

Comment: I'm not asking how many items there are in each features, but what is the shape of the `features` variable. What do you get when running `print(features.shape)`?